# jul to slf4j with logback binding do not print if root level below threshold

Tags: slf4j, logback, java.util.logging

I configured in my application jul over slf4j with logback binding

logging.properties

```
handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
```

logback.xml

```
    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
      <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

<root level="WARN">   
   <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>

<logger name="x.y.z" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-ORDER-MANAGER" />
</logger>
```

In my class x.y.z.Foo if I reference directly slf4j as below all works fine:

```
slf4jlogger.info("Get email info for order {} ", request);
```

If I use JUL it doesn't work:

```
jullogger.log(INFO, "getFullOrder info for order {0} ", request);
```

It starts to work only if I change the root level for logback and set it to the corresponding value (root level -> INFO).

Comment: What happens if the ASYNC-ORDER-MANAGER is attached to the root logger. Do you see any difference?

Comment: Nothing changed. I found a work-around to make it works. I defined the same logger on logback and on logging.properties (e.g. logging.properties --> x.y.z.level=DEBUG

Comment: According to my experience the `LevelChangePropagator` is only able to propagate the level (change) to JUL when the _full_ category name is configured in the `<logger>` config, will say: `<logger name="x.y.z.Foo" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">...</logger>` is required. Though this observation applies to a configuration using Logback I think the problem is the same here.